# Will Ortools/gurobi runs faster if given more constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, or-tools

Hi I'm trying to solve Operation problems with ortools or gurobi. I'm wondering if I provide some explicit constraints, like the variables should fall in [a,b], will that accelerate running speed or make it even more complicated than before?

Answer (score 2):

In mixed integer optimization it is often advisable to add additional constraints if they cut of linear solutions that do not fulfil the integrability constraints. These [mixed-integer cuts](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Mixed-integer_cuts) are designed to bring the optimal linear solution closer to the optimal integer solution and can sometime yield significant speed-ups. Commercial solvers like gurobi will generate some of these cuts automatically.

Additionally commercial solvers will most likely ignore redundant constraints that you added if they don't help. So normally you don't loose any performance.

So usually it is a good idea to add these kinds of constraints.

Note that sometimes changing the problem will also change the branch and cut order. So it might happen that you were lucky before and got an integer solution fast and the new solutions needs longer due to other branching. So when solving MIPs you sometimes see counter-intuitive runtime behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Reduced domains will most likely help.
Adding more constraints may help. It depends on their complexity and their number.

When you say or-tools, what do you refer to?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried MIP solver at beginning, but it seems like can't have a feasible solution to a 10000 variables problem. But when I switched to CP-SAT and added the constraints above, it did have an optimal solution and run much faster then before.